# javascript customized input property

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I used to see part of `html/javascript/AngularJS` like this:

```
<input type="integer" min="0" ng-model="qty" required>
```

I know basic usage of html/javascript, what I don't understand is that html and javascript only support `input type="text"` or `input type="password"`.

How `type="integer"` is supported? and how attribute `"min"` is supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`type="integer"` is not supported by angular.

There is a `type="number"` that is supported, but this follows the introduction of the `number` input in HTML5.  So, in HTML5, there **is** a `number` supported.

`min` and `max` are attributes of the HTML5 input as well.

Angular wraps the `input` in a built-in directive.  So, angular offers a shim for supporting these types of inputs for browsers that do not support HTML5 inputs as well.

Comment: I used to see some other "weird" properties too. So, is it possible that I use: input type="anyValueIWouldLike"?

Comment: not typically. you can see the input types supported by angular on the input documentation page.

Comment: "ng-model" is not part of HTML5, right? How AngularJS did the trick of using "ng-model" as a property of html input?

Comment: this is fundamental to how angular works. it's suggest reading some documentation. there is a good article called, "conceptual overview" which will help. "ng-model" is an angular directive.